# Windows server RDP session remote control

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, rdp

I have RDP access and administrative privileges on Windows Server 2008 R2. While other users are connected via RDP, I can remotely contol their session. When user is disconnected (but the session is still alive), I can't use remote contol for some reason. Is there any way to login to user's session without entering his password?

Comment: No, this would remove the inherent security of windows RDP and Remote Assistance. There should be other ways of changing things remotely than using shadowing. Let us know what you are trying to ultimately accomplish. Also more of a Server Fault question.

Answer (score 2):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281156

Cannot remote control a session which is in disconnected state.